# How do you run scripts in Jade template sub blocks?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, pug

I'm using Jade and I have a template and a content block. I can run scripts in the template but how do I run the scripts in the content block?

Here's a bare bones example, mintemplate.jade:

```
doctype html
html
head
    script.
        alert('Layout Ready!');
body
    h1 Test
        block content
```

and test.jade:

```
extends minlayout
script.
    alert('Content Ready!');

block content
    h2 Content
```

The 'Layout Ready' alert works fine but the 'Content Ready' alert never appears.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you need to move script declaration under block definition

```
extends minlayout

block content

    script.

        alert('Content Ready!');

    h2 Content
```

[Template Inheritance](http://www.learnjade.com/tour/template-inheritance/)